# If $\,1 + \frac {1}{2}+\frac {1}{3} +..... +\frac {1}{p-1} = \frac {a}{b}$ then $p\mid a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac 1{p-1} = \frac ab$, where $a,b$ are integers. Show that $p\mid a$. (**Hint:** As $a$ runs through $U_p$, so does $a^{-1}$.)

P.S. $U_p$ means the group of of invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and I believe for prime $p$, $U_p = \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: For prime $p$, $U_p = \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If you take $\pmod p$ on both side,  do you see that $\sum_\limits {n=1}^{p-1} 1/n \equiv \sum  \limits_ {n=1} ^{p-1} n \pmod p   $ ?

Comment: Oh, this is what "run through" mean. Thank you so much!