Prime divisors of numerators of partial sums of the harmonic series?
I observed something about several partial sums of the harmonic series, and I wonder if you know more to the story.  Recall that the $n$th partial sum of the harmonic series is
$$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}.$$
Write each partial sum $H_n$ as a reduced fraction
$$H_n=\frac{N_n}{D_n}.$$
(Thus, $\mathrm{gcd}(N_n,D_n)=1$ for each $n$.)  The curious thing that I noticed is that if $p$ is prime and $n=p-1$, then $p^2$ is often divisor of the numerator $N_n$.  For example, $H_4=5^2/12$, $H_6=7^2/20$, $H_{10}=11^2\cdot 61/2520$, etc.
Does this happen for every prime $p$ beyond these?  I've checked another 50 of them, but this is obviously a very small sample size.
Thank you.

I found it.  This is Wolstenholme's theorem.  The link is to the Wikipedia page.  Thank you again.

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910912/divisibility-of-the-pth-stirling-number-of-the-first-kind-editof-the-second-or and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318510/if-p-is-prime-amd-1-frac12-frac13-ldots-frac1p-1-fracab and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325491/proof-of-wolstenholmes-theorem and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203875/if-1-frac-12-frac-13-frac-1p-1-frac-ab-then and probably many more.
